# Curved Carousel (Bezier path?)

Tags: jquery, carousel, bezier

Is there any well-known method to create a carousel along a bezier's curved path, with jQuery or CSS3 or...?

Ideally, the items should move along the path, with their vertical axis being perpendicular to the path, something like this:

[image: curved / semi-circular carousel]

Many thanks for any input,

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/ and the code can be found here https://github.com/codrops/Arctext. Just try replacing the text with images and create a slider.

Answer (score 1):

Need the same Bezier Carousel style and find Theta Carousel :
http://theta-carousel.com

Here is an exampe provided with bezier : 
http://theta-carousel.com/carousel-example.html#example=bezier1

There is a lot of parameters but you have a UI to configure it, a very nice feature : 
http://theta-carousel.com/#features